# Not able to create a Firebase collection

Tags: swift, firebase

Hi I'm doing a school project for building a instagram clone in which I need to create a comment section for users posts for which I need to get realtime updates for it from the Firestore but to do that I need to create a collection for it and I was not able to do so. I'm not getting any errors in Xcode.

[image: Image of code]

```
    static var FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_ALL_POSTS = FIRESTORE_ROOT.collection("all_posts")

    static var FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_COMMENTS = FIRESTORE_ROOT.collection("comments")
    static func FIRESTORE_COMMENTS_DOCUMENT_POSTID(postId: String) -> DocumentReference {
        return FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_COMMENTS.document(postid)
    }
}
```

Comment: "school project for building a instagram clone" interesting... btw please don't post your code as images, just paste it in instead

Comment: ok this is my first time asking a question will do it like it next time

Answer (score 1):

A collections are automatically created when the first document is written to it, and it is automatically removed when the last documented is deleted for it. There is no API to create/remove collections outside of that.

None of your code writes any data to the database yet, so that explains why no collection is created. If you want to create the `FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_COMMENTS` collection, write a document to it as shown in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#swift_5).